# How can all the routers remember my leased IP? Shouldn't it change if I connect to a different router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dhcp

If i have understood this correctly. The DHCP server will lease you an IP address, when you first connect to let's say a school network. If I move from the 8th floor to the 2nd floor, then I'll most likely connect to a different router. If the lease hasn't expired yet, how does the new router figure out what my leased IP is? and won't that be a little confusing if let's say i am connected to subnetwork 192.168.3.0 but have leased an IP that belongs to another subnetwork?

Comment: When you move from 8th floor to 2nd you're likely not connecting to a different "router" but a different "access point" behind the same router on the same network.  The last few lines of your question make less sense, what dhcp server handed out 192.168.3.0?

Comment: I am sorry. I haven't understood this fully, so I guess my example way off. The way i saw it was that a school network will have multiple routers across the building, and each router is connected to at least one private network. So if I move from one place to another, then I'll be connecting to a different subnetwork.  Clearly that's not the case. Do you know where the leased IP will most likely be stored?

Comment: People are router happy these days. If they don't have good wifi they plug in another router.  The school network doesn't have multiple routers tho, instead it has multiple access points and managed switches.  What people do at home with "routers" (as evidenced by reading superuser) is what's confusing you.  But in general at home people should only have one router, then if they need more wifi they should add an access point.  Where the ip is stored?  Did you mean the dhcp server or on you computer?  If you mean your computer we need to know the OS.

Comment: It makes much more sense now, thank you. I was trying to understand how a large scale private network keeps track off and updates all of its leased IP addresses. How someone can walk around with a laptop and connect from anywhere and still have the same private IP. I was a little bit confused about where the DHCP is stored, and how every access point you connect to will know which IP you have leased.

Comment: Another point, what we call a router at home is really a router, DHCP server, unmanaged switch, wifi access point and perhaps even a modem that are all built into a single chassis and called a  router.  It's really 3 or 4 networking devices conveniently wrapped in one package.

Comment: Every router has a DHCP server? So for a small network the DHCP server will be stored in the router. For a large network, a seperate DHCP server running on a computer will be neccessary? Thank you again. I think i'm beginning to understand this much more clearly.

Comment: Every home router has a DHCP server built in... In larger networks the DHCP server may or not be the same physical box as the router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens when you ask for an IP address:

```
# dhclient -v usb0
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/usb0/9c:eb:e8:2c:46:66
Sending on   LPF/usb0/9c:eb:e8:2c:46:66
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on usb0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x663c9e23)
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.11.91 on usb0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x239e3c66)
DHCPOFFER of 192.168.11.91 from 192.168.11.1
DHCPACK of 192.168.11.91 from 192.168.11.1
bound to 192.168.11.91 -- renewal in 34984 seconds.
```

This happens in Linux, for an ethernet interface (called `usb0`) but the substance of it is the same for all OSes and ll interfaces.

Though not completely obvious from the above, the interface sends on its MAC address (the universal, unique address which every network interface card NIC possesses) as it tries to discover whether a DHCP server exists on the wire (or on the airwaves, if it is connected to a wifi network).

Once it has received a positive reply, it will ask for the previous IP address it held (192.168.11.91, in the case above). This is done so as to minimize the impact of disconnections: some network programs, like `openvpn`, `mosh`, and a properly configured `ssh` are capable of reconnecting seamlessly to their servers after a local disconnection, and re-obtaining the same LAN address will contribute to make that possible.

The server checks whether the required IP address is within the range it has for dishing out IP addresses, whether the address is taken, and, if it is taken, whether it is allocated to the very same MAC address which is asking for it. If the answer to the first question is **yes** and to the second is **no**, then you can have the IP address you asked for. But you can have it also if the answer is **yes** to all three questions, as it happened to me above.

Comment: Can you explain how it is determined that you need to get a new IP address; e.g., when you carry your laptop from your home to a friend's home?  Does the multifunction (router/modem/access point) box detect that the laptop is using a source address that isn't supposed to be in its network?

Comment: @Scott As I said above: your pc asks for the same IP address it had the last time it was connected (`DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.11.91 on usb0 ` above), and the router checks whether it can dish out such an address: suppose its range of assignable addresses were `192.168.1.100-192.168.1.200`, then it could not possibly assign 192.168.11.91, and the pc would get a new address.